# How do i write a nested for loop with multiple ifs in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know how i can optimise this code?

```
def remove_double_quotes(df):
  initial_headers = list(df.columns)
  for x in initial_headers:
     for i in range(len(df)):
        if type(df[x][i]) == str:
           if df[x][i].find('"') != -1:
              df[x][i] = df[x][i].replace('"','')
```

basically i am searching each cell for in the dataframe for any string which contains double apostrophe and removing it. I am looking for a cleaner and faster code.

Comment: You are probably looking for an `and` operator in python, which can be used like that: `if (type(df[x][i]) == str) and (if df[x][i].find('"') != -1):`

Comment: @PawelKam yea agree. but do you know how to form the entire thing into a single list comprehension?

Comment: You mention a dataframe, but you haven't tagged any library. Can you do so? I'm guessing you want [tag:pandas], but that term is used in a few other places.

Comment: @Imran Tan I would advise against using list comprehensions when you need double iteration with conditions because it will be difficult to understand. However, you you really need to, the list comprehension lies under the following schema: `[item for secondloop_items in firstloop_items for item in secondloop_items if (item == sth) and (item != sth_else)]`

Comment: @PawelKam yea i agree with you on that part. but my laptop is like on 8gb ram only haha and i gotta churn this data cleansing asap (more than 1 million lines). Thanks you!

Comment: Just for make it a little cleaner, you don't need to find double apostrophe then remove it, delete line `if df[x][i].find('"') != -1:` and only use `df[x][i] = df[x][i].replace('"','')` . if there is double apostrophe in the string it'll be removed, & if there's not, nothing happends.